# Problem accessing: Unauthorized, OpenDaylight

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

Im tring to access ODL, but I got this error 
** I've installed all the features**
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJcAy.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqN00.png)

Answer (score 0):

can you do:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://$ODL_IP:8181/restconf/streams
```

that is user admin, password admin (the default). The screen shot you
posted is just an unauthorized so I can guess that you didn't give the
right credentials when you were asked. Doing the curl above will verify
if that part is working or not.

Comment: i got a message like that  {}dalal.dalal-virtualBox:~$

Comment: Yeah, '{}' is a correct response. You can try /modules if you want to see more output. Looks like things are working properly though with admin:admin credentials

Comment: can you please get your email?

Comment: You can find it publicly, like here: https://wiki.opendaylight.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=329342